# SQL case when date challenge

Tags: sql-server

So i tried searching for the issue. But to be honest, i am not even sure what would be causing my code to work the first time, but then replacing the result with an error. I might be lacking something fundamental. If this is the case then i apologise.

Here is my code

```
UPDATE tableA
       SET tableA.X= 
              CASE WHEN tableB.A <= 0 AND tableA.X = '' THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE(), 103), 103)
                     WHEN TableB.A > 0 THEN '' 
                      ELSE 'Error' 
END
FROM tableB JOIN tableA 
ON tableB.key=tableA.key;
```

What i am trying to do is fairly simple. When i detect a situation where tableB.A is 0 then i want to update tableA.X to todays date. However i only want to replace this date with something else when tableB.A becomes greater then 0 again.

What is currently happening is that when i run the code the first time it works. It replaces tableB.A with todays date. However the next day, it replaces all dates with error.

**Example result:**  TableB.A = 0  TableA.X = 26/03/2017

**Tomorrow**
TableB.A = 0
TableA.X = 'Error

Why does this happen?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Don't store your dates as text.

Comment: This is an X-Y problem. You're looking for a solution to a problem which wouldn't exist if your database was designed correctly. SQL has "date" and "datetime" type columns for a reason - use them. Storing dates as text is a terrible idea - for the reason you've discovered above and about a dozen others.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate the help. I'll change the column type.

Comment: You have got to be kidding me.  After you assign a value to TableA.X is the condition `tableA.X = ''` still true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `AND` condition on the first `WHEN`. In here you are placing today's date when table B is lower or equal than 0 **and** table A's X is empty.

```
tableB.A <= 0 AND tableA.X = ''
```

After executing for the first time (assuming X is empty string and B is negative), you are replacing X's value with todays date. So tomorrow, for the same expression and value of B, the condition will **not** be true (because X isn't empty, it has today's value). Since it's not true and the 2nd condition

```
TableB.A > 0
```

is still false (assuming B's value is still negative or zero), then it will jump to the `ELSE` (Error).

A solution would be keeping X's old value in the `ELSE`.

```
ELSE tableA.X END
```

Or if you want to set today's value on each execution, then remove the X empty comparison on the first `WHEN`.

```
... WHEN tableB.A <= 0 THEN ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that is very much appreciated. Your logic is concise and well explained.

Comment: Please mark as solved if it helped you. Glad to help :)

Comment: Done i think :)

Answer (score 0):

You have updated **tableA.X** with this condition **"tableB.A <= 0** AND **tableA.X = ''** to current date.

Now **tableA.X** is no longer = ' ' (as it has a date), so it will enter the `ELSE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below script

```
    UPDATE a
   SET a.X= 
          CASE WHEN isnull(convert(int,b.A ),0)<= 0 AND isnull(a.X,0) = 0 THEN  convert(varchar,getdate(),103)
                 WHEN b.A > 0 THEN '' 
                  ELSE 'Error' END
    FROM b JOIN a 
    ON b.key=a.key
```